# toast doesn't show correct style - nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-toastify

I'm using `react-toastify`.

_app.tsx:

```
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

...

  return (
    <AppStateProvider>
      <MainProvider>
      <HeaderProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <ToastContainer
          position="top-right"
          autoClose={5000}
          hideProgressBar={false}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick
          rtl={true}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover
        />
       </HeaderProvider>
       </MainProvider>
    </AppStateProvider>
  );
}
```

in my component:

```
toast.success( "success")
```

but it shows like this:

[image]

but at demo it shows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here goes my first answer on SO!
Ran into a similar situation while trying out React-Toastify as well.

Basically you need to state the theme you want your toast to be.

e.g.

```
toast.success("success", {
  theme: "colored"
})
```

"colored" is the theme you are looking for

```
toast.success("success", {
  theme: "dark"
})
```

"dark" is also available.

If you don't provide any themes you get the result in the picture you uploaded in the question

Answer (score 0):

Remove `rtl={true}` in `ToastContainer`;

https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/enable-right-to-left-support